# Mocha with babel transpile 3rd party dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mocha.js, babeljs, native-base

I have a react native app that is setup with Redux and Redux Saga.
I have unit tests using mocha, all tests used to work fine until I added `native-base`.

When I test now, it throws this error

```
[poject-path]/node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import connectStyle from './src/connectStyle';
                                                              ^^^^^^
```

I have a setup with babel, is there anyway I can transpile that dependency? or do something without changing my code?

What I currently did in my file that is causing the problem is the following

```
const Toast = null;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test')
    Toast = require('native-base').Toast;
```

The tests work with the above, but I was just testing to make sure it passes and it did, however that's not a good way to do it.

There is a similar problem in their GitHub Repo [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/21)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a setup with babel, is there anyway I can transpile that dependency

By convention, all `npm` modules should be provided in repository in transplated form, usually, by perform prepublush script and index link into `dist` directory. But in general case `babel` can easily transplate any dependencies, by customizing `ignore` regex in configutation

For example, when using `webpack` with `babel-loader`, config with force transpiling `MODULE_ONE` and `MODULE_TWO` will have following view:

```
{
    test: /(\.js)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules(?!(?:\/|\\)((MODULE_ONE)|(MODULE_TWO)))/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'] }
}
```